# get value from dataframe based on row values without using column names

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to get a value situated on the third column from a pandas dataframe by knowing the values of interest on the first two columns, which point me to the right value to fish out. I do not know the row index, just the values I need to look for on the first two columns. The combination of values from the first two columns is unique, so I do not expect to get a subset of the dataframe, but only a row. I do not have column names and I would like to avoid using them.

Consider the dataframe `df`:

```
a    1    bla 
b    2    tra
b    3    foo
b    1    bar
c    3    cra
```

I would like to get `tra` from the second row, based on the `b` and `2` combination that I know beforehand. I've tried subsetting with

```
df = df.loc['b', :]
```

which returns all the rows with `b` on the same column (provided I've read the data with `index_col = 0`) but I am not able to pass multiple conditions on it without crashing or knowing the index of the row of interest. I tried both `df.loc` and `df.iloc`.

In other words, ideally I would like to get `tra` without even using row indexes, by doing something like:

```
df[(df[,0] == 'b' & df[,1] == `2`)][2]
```

Any suggestions? Probably it is something simple enough, but I have the tendency to use the same syntax as in R, which apparently is not compatible.

Thank you in advance

Comment: `df.loc[df.index=='b',:]` ?

Comment: @anky that returns all the rows with the index `b` right? Equivalent to `df = df.loc['b', :]` as I wrote in the question. I would need a double condition with the second column being `2`

Comment: can you update the question and the expected output with this usecase?

Comment: well, I did mention in the question: "I would like to get `tra` from the second row, based on the `b` and `2` combination that I know beforehand." isn't that what you mean?

Comment: Try this read the file with `index_col=[0,1]` , then do `df.iloc[df.index.get_loc(("b",2)):]` ?

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. I tried, but I get a `NotImplementedError: only the default get_loc method is currently supported for MultiIndex`

Comment: you might need to upgrade pandas if possible

Comment: sorry @anky, it was another thing that led to that error. multiple row indexing works. 
i can get that value with `df = pd.read_csv(path, sep='\t', index_col=[0, 1])`, `df = df.iloc[df.index.get_loc(("b", 2)):]`, and `df.iloc[0]`

i will post an answer mentioning your help. thank you. not that straight forward tho :)

Answer (score 1):

As @anky has suggested, a way to do this without knowing the column names nor the row index where your value of interest is, would be to read the file in a pandas dataframe using multiple column indexing.

For the provided example, knowing the column indexes at least, that would be:

```
df = pd.read_csv(path, sep='\t', index_col=[0, 1])
```

then, you can use:

```
df = df.iloc[df.index.get_loc(("b", 2)):]
df.iloc[0]
```

to get the value of interest.

Thanks again @anky for your help. If you found this question useful, please upvote @anky 's comment in the posted question.

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably use `pd.query` for that:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(index=['a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'c'], data={"col1": [1, 2, 3, 1, 3], "col2": ['bla', 'tra', 'foo', 'bar', 'cra']})
df

   col1 col2
a   1   bla
b   2   tra
b   3   foo
b   1   bar
c   3   cra

df.query('col1 == 2 and col2 == "tra"')
    col1 col2
b   2   tra
```

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. but that implies using column names and knowing beforehand the value I am looking for (e.g., `tra`). however, I've tried it, but I get `TypeError: 'method' object is not subscriptable`